# C# Forms: Lock Main form and process another form

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I want to create something like this.

[image]

When the button clicks main form will lock/disable/inaccessible. Then the another form load and do some processing. 
(actually when the button clicked, it will read some text from a file and write to db. I put progress bar to give a nice look)

As I said I want to lock/disable/inaccessible main form and load the another form.

How can I do this ?

Please Help 
Yohan

Comment: Is `Form.ShowDialog()` not working for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent WinForms from losing focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693465/how-to-prevent-winforms-from-losing-focus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Form().ShowDialog()` will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

`oldForm.Hide()` and `newForm().ShowDialog()`

Comment: Why are you hiding the first form? OP has just asked to make it inaccessible not hide it.

Answer (score 1):

as J.N. mentioned, ShowDialog will work, but I think you will need to have your processing code in the new form you open up, as the program will only return and 'unlock' your main form after the new form has finished and closed.

Edit I just saw the comments below the original post, I guess this has been sorted, but I'll leave my comments above just in case