# How to prevent WinForms from losing focus?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, focus

How to prevent my "About-Form" (no input-boxes, OK-button only) from losing focus, to force the user to click "OK"? I tried Validation and ErrorProvider. I tried also to delegate Show, Activate and Focus like this:

```
AboutForm myAboutForm = new AboutForm();
myAboutForm.Deactivate += delegate { myAboutForm.Show(); myAboutForm.Activate(); };
myAboutForm.Show();
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your about form a [Modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) window dialog.

```
AboutForm myAboutForm = new AboutForm();
myAboutForm.ShowDialog();
```

From MSDN - [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx):

> Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your Abort Form as [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). A modal window is (per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)):

> In user interface design, a modal window is a child window that
>   requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating
>   the parent application, thus preventing the workflow on the
>   application main window. Modal windows are often called heavy windows
>   or modal dialogs because the window is often used to display a dialog
>   box.

For example,

`myAboutForm.ShowDialog();` instead of `myAboutForm.Show();` so:

```
AboutForm myAboutForm = new AboutForm();
myAboutForm.ShowDialog();
```

Read more at [MSDN on displaying modal and modeless windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),

> A modal form or dialog box must be closed or hidden before you can
>   continue working with the rest of the application.

Finally, I am not sure if that [Deactivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx) works the way you think, per MSDN:

> Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.

and

> You can use this event to perform tasks such as updating another
>   window in your application with data from the deactivated form.

Answer (score 3):

Show the form as a modal dialog:

`myAboutForm.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1):

```
AboutForm myAboutForm = new AboutForm();
myAboutForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows, desktop is on highest priority. You cannot block user from accessing desktop if your app is running. However, there are tricks to do it. You just set topmost property of form, so that user will always see on top above all applications. ShowDialog will keep your form on top of your application.